# Mongoose - Find an Array of strings inside a filed with array of ObjectIDs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model which stores Object IDs from another model. Now I need to find inside that model which contains specific ids the other model.

My Schema is :
I have a model with a field containing object ids. like..

```
const SpiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  createdat: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  blends: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'blend',
  }],
  flavors: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'flavor',
  }],
  ingredients: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ingredient',
  }],
  regions: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'region',
  }],
});
```

Now the document looks like this..

```
{ blends: [ 5cf296751771e6157cc2b257, 5cf296f1c61d6739b0903ef5 ],
   flavors: [ 5cf2b268acac9e261459ea3a ],
   ingredients: [ 5cf2b281acac9e261459ea3b ],
   regions: [],
   _id: 5cf4162d95aa7d28e0c4e324,
   name: 'themeal',
   description: 'sldkjf ldskjflksdj f\r\nlorem salute saloni',
   createdat: 2019-06-02T18:32:13.270Z,
   __v: 0,
   image: '5cf4162d95aa7d28e0c4e324.jpg' } ]
```

I have an array of blends comming in from front-end like this..

```
query.blends: [ '5cf2956b1771e6157cc2b256', '5cf296751771e6157cc2b257' ]
```

I need to find all documents inside spice schema which contains these two blends..

Currently I'm trying to achieve this by doing:

```
const spicesQuery = Spice.find();
spicesQuery.where({blends: {$in: query.blends}});
const spices = spicesQuery.sort({name: 1}).exec();
console.log(spices);
```

I get all the spices in the model.. Not just the one's which have these two blends..

Answer (score 1):

use [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all)

```
spicesQuery.where({blends: {$all: query.blends}});
const spices = await spicesQuery.sort({name: 1}).exec();
```

Comment: This did the job... Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, you could accept the answer to close the question.